# Page-wide table/header on a two-column document?

Tags: tables, header-footer, two-column

I am trying to reproduce an old exam document from 1980 in LaTeX. However, I cannot acheive the desired result.

Here's the code I've got so far;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\geometry{
 letterpaper,
 total={7.5in,9.5in},
 left=0.5in,
 top=1in,}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\circlef[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=black] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{0.7in} >{\centering}m{0.2in} >{\centering}m{1.25in} >{\centering}m{4.5in}|}
    \hline
    {\large SECTION} & {\Huge \textbf{1}} & {\large Time--30 minutes\\45 Questions} & For each question in this section, choose the best answer and fill in the corresponding oval on the answer sheet.\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\twocolumn

\begin{framed}
Each question below consists of a word in capital letters, followed by five lettered words or phrases. Choose the word or phrase that is most nearly \underline{opposite} in meaning to the word in capital letters. Since some of the questions require you to distinguish fine shades of meaning, consider all the choices before deciding which is best.

\vspace{5pt}

Example:

\vspace{5pt}
\begin{adjustwidth}{0.35cm}{}
GOOD:\quad (A) sour\quad (B) bad\quad (C) red\\
(D) hot\quad (E) ugly
\end{adjustwidth}

\begin{flushright}
\vspace{-15pt}
{\tiny \circled{A} \circlef{B} \circled{C} \circled{D} \circled{E}}\end{flushright}
\vspace{-10pt}
\end{framed}

\break

\begin{framed}
Each sentence below has one or two blanks, each blakc indicating that something has been ommited. Beneath the sentence are five lettered words or sets of words. Choose the word or set of words that, when inserted into the sentence, \underline{best} fits the meaning of the sentence as a whole.

\vspace{5pt}
Example:
\vspace{5pt}
\begin{adjustwidth}{0.35cm}{}
Although its publicity has been -{}-{}-{}-, the film itself is intelligent, well-acted, handsomely produced and altogether -{}-{}-{}-.

\vspace{5pt}
(A) tasteless. .respectable\quad (B) extensive. .moderate\\
(C) sophisticated. .amateur\quad (D) risqué. .crude\\
(E) perfect. .spectacular
\end{adjustwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\vspace{-15pt}
{\tiny \circlef{A} \circled{B} \circled{C} \circled{D} \circled{E}}\end{flushright}
\vspace{-10pt}
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

And this is what I'm trying to reproduce.
[image]

And this is what my reproduction looks like so far... and it doesn't look quite right.
[image]

I am wondering about what's wrong with my approach and how I can optimize it.

I want to put the page-wide table at the top of the framed boxes, and also on the same page. Evidently, I'd also would like to fix the text alignment for the rightmost cell as well as the table borders.

If it also isn't too much to ask, I'd like to know how to turn those small circles into ellipses, just like on the reference photo.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tikz:

- a first node for the first frame with 3 minipages
- a second node for the 2nd southwest of the previous node
- the 3rd to the southeast

for ellipses, a yscale or \usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}
I did not modify the adjustwidth, I do not know the package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\geometry{
letterpaper,
total={7.5in,9.5in},
left=0.5in,
top=1in,}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt,yscale=0.8] (char) {#1};}}
\newcommand*\circlef[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt, fill=black,yscale=0.8] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
%%            first  frame referenced by A in the node
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw](A)at(0,0){%
    \begin{minipage}{0.8in}
      \centering
      \large SECTION
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.2in}
      \centering
      \Huge \textbf{1}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{1.5in}
      \centering
      Time --- $30$~minutes

      $45$~questions
    \end{minipage}%
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{4.5in}
      For each question in this section, choose the best answer and fill in the corresponding oval on the answer sheet.
    \end{minipage}%
  };
  %%  second  frame frame offset by 2ex
  \node [draw,below right,yshift=-2ex]at(A.south west){
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      Each question below consists of a word in capital letters, followed by five lettered words or phrases. Choose the word or phrase that is most nearly \underline{opposite} in meaning to the word in capital letters. Since some of the questions require you to distinguish fine shades of meaning, consider all the choices before deciding which is best.

      \vspace{5pt}

      Example:

      \vspace{5pt}
      \begin{adjustwidth}{0.35cm}{}
        GOOD:\quad (A) sour\quad (B) bad\quad (C) red\\
        (D) hot\quad (E) ugly
      \end{adjustwidth}

      \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{-15pt}
        {\tiny \circled{A} \circlef{B} \circled{C} \circled{D} \circled{E}}\end{flushright}

    \end{minipage}%
  };
  %%  third  frame frame offset by 2ex
  \node [draw,below left,yshift=-2ex](C)at(A.south east){
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
      Each sentence below has one or two blanks, each blakc indicating that something has been ommited. Beneath the sentence are five lettered words or sets of words. Choose the word or set of words that, when inserted into the sentence, \underline{best} fits the meaning of the sentence as a whole.

      \vspace{5pt}
      Example:
      \vspace{5pt}
      \begin{adjustwidth}{0.35cm}{}
        Although its publicity has been -{}-{}-{}-, the film itself is intelligent, well-acted, handsomely produced and altogether -{}-{}-{}-.

        \vspace{5pt}
        (A) tasteless. .respectable\quad (B) extensive. .moderate\\
        (C) sophisticated. .amateur\quad (D) risqué. .crude\\
        (E) perfect. .spectacular
      \end{adjustwidth}
      \begin{flushright}
        \vspace{-15pt}
        {\tiny \circlef{A} \circled{B} \circled{C} \circled{D} \circled{E}}\end{flushright}
    \end{minipage}%
  };
\end{tikzpicture}\hfill\null
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is another issue now. I can't add any text under those boxes in any neat way whereas I could do that before with the `framed` package and the `\twocolumn` command. I suppose I create another minipage to compensate?

Comment: I ended up using a minipage without `draw` and it worked. Many thanks!